# Change base class from derived class permanently?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

So, my problem is that i want to modify my parent class Board from a derived class in such a way that it applies to all other objects of the derived class. Ex. If I input a 3 on getTest() in players[1] players[2] will be able to print that same value. Is this posible?

```
  class Board {
    public:
        int test;
        virtual void getTest() = 0;


};

class Player : public Board{
    public:
        int playerNum;
        Player(int _playerNum){
            playerNum = _playerNum;

        }
        void printTest(){
            cout << "The value of test is: " << Board::test;
        }
        void getTest(){
            cin >> Board::test;
        }

};




int main(){


    Player players[] = {1,2};

    players[1].getTest();
    players[0].printTest();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Board::test` should be declared `static` if it's state should be shared across all classes

Comment: Make `test` a static variable.

Comment: I would be careful recommending `static` as a go-to. `static` would share the state for _all instances, everywhere_ -- which isn't very nice in terms of design.

Comment: But it does seem to be what's being asked for, no?

Comment: @Putnam I should clarify... The current usage pattern, having a non-static member function of a sub-class `Player` assigning the value of `static` variable in the interface isn't nice in terms of design.

Comment: It does, but there is often a big difference between getting what you asked for and getting what you needed.

Comment: Indeed. Let's just randomly guess what OP wants/needs instead of answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to share state between all instances that derive from `Board`.

As mentioned in the comments, if `Board::test` were given the `static` storage-class duration, this would be a variable shared across *all instances of `Player`* and any other classes that derive from `Board` now and forever. Technically, the variable is actually a member of the *type* rather than instances of the type. This *will work*, however in terms of design, it has some strange implications.

Namely, `Player::getTest()` is a non-static member-function, which sets `static` state that will be shared across all derived classes of `Board`. This can work as a quick and dirty change to code, but can lead to maintenance burdens and cognitive overhead. For example, if you have code in different subsystems like a `Player` and `Widget` that both implement `Board`, you get into a case where:

```cpp
// subsystem A:
player.getState();

// subsystem B:
widget.printTest(); // not obvious that this comes from the player in "subsystem A"
```

The bigger the code gets, the harder it is to understand.

Additionally, `static` variables have issues working across translation units that can lead to initialization-order problems -- and it's often a mess that's not worth fighting with.

---

Depending on what it is you actually intend to share, often times it can be better for design to explicitly state as such using an object that explicitly indicates its shared ownership -- such as a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

This won't be implicitly passed to everything as you originally requested -- but that's actually a good thing since you can explicitly state what data you want shared and where. This also lets you decide if ever there's a case where you don't want *everything* shared between them, you can design it as such.

A simple example with your current code would instead be done like:

```cpp
class Board {
    public:
        virtual void getTest() = 0;
};

class Player : public Board{
    public:
        int playerNum;
        std::shared_ptr<int> test;
        Player(int _playerNum, std::shared_ptr<int> _test){
            playerNum = _playerNum;
            test = _test;
        }
        void printTest(){
            cout << "The value of test is: " << *test;
        }
        void getTest(){
            cin >> *test;
        }
};

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<int> test = std::make_shared<int>(0);

    // explicitly share 'test' between the two players
    Player players[] = {Player{1,test}, Player{2,test}};

    players[1].getTest();
    players[0].printTest();

    return 0;
}
```

This would produce the same results as you originally requested, but it explicitly shared `test` rather than implicitly doing this behind `static` variables.

Explicitly stating the shared state here also allows you to produce more `Player` objects later that might share a different set of `test` state than the first created ones (depending on what this state is, this can be quite useful).

Overall, it's often better in terms of design for readability and overall cognitive overhead to be explicit about the data you want shared.